# How is f:view in useful in jsf 2.0?

Tags: jsf

In jsf 2.0 the `<f:view>..</f:view>` (assuming f corresponds to faces tags) is said to be useful but I can see no actual use of it, if it can be omitted.

P.S.: I actually found not comments on this matter in specs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set the contentType (in some cases useful for Safari browsers), locale (I18N, L10N) and encoding with it:

```
<f:view locale="#{sample.locale}" encoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html">
```